# Dynamic hyperlink using MailApp.sendEmail at Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to code a simple reminder spreadsheet, which should work by a monthly trigger.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13UKPI01g0AQqSOYqPVsug-V5TqMaC29Gk1LmdQNCFEk/edit?usp=sharing) is an example.

The idea is to use query/importrange formulas on this sheet, so the range used by the script will be updated automatically.

About the script, I've found an interesting article where it uses the sheet range and sends custom messages to everyone:

```
function EnviarLembretes() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var PrimeiraLinha = 2;
    var NumLinhas = sheet.getRange(2, 4).getValue();
    var Lista = sheet.getRange(PrimeiraLinha, 1, NumLinhas, 3);
    var DadosLista = Lista.getValues();
      for(i in DadosLista){
        var row = DadosLista [i];
        var email = row [0];
        var subject = row [1];
        var message = row [2];

        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);
      }
}
```

Worked like a charm, but that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Don't know if it's possible (maybe with HTML), but I would like to send an image (same to everyone), with a custom hyperlink embedded on it. So, I would adjust the formula to just catch from the sheet an e-mail address and the hyperlink to be added to the image.

Plus, I'm a bit concerned with "SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();" which is being used in the script. As the script will be triggered monthly and the sheet updates automatically, I do not pretend to open the file anymore. Therefore, I'm looking for a way to certify the active sheet will be the one which is accessible by the URL I've shared in this post.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where does the custom hyperlink come from? A cell on the sheet?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a cell on the sheet. Every row should have a specific hyperlink which is going to be used on the e-mail.

Comment: Image size won't be an issue, since the image in specific is kinda small and all rigs at work have at least a 720p monitor

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't fully tested this script but it should work.

This will send an in-line image stored in Google Drive to the email address with a hyperlink retrieved from column C of the sheet.

Using `.getSheetByName('Página1');` ensures that the script will always look for this sheet to find the information.

The size of the image can be set by changing the width and height values in the `<img>` tag.

```
function EnviarLembretes() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet.getSheetByName('Página1');

    var Lista = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 3);
    var DadosLista = Lista.getValues();

    var image = DriveApp.getFileById("-------"); //Get the image from Google Drive file ID
    var blob = image.getBlob(); //Get the image blob
    var imageBlob = Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(blob.getBytes()); //Re-encode the image for sending

    for (var i = 0; i < DadosLista.length; i++) { // I would NOT use a for in loop for this task - you chould change to for( ; ; )

        var body = //Create the body of the message here in HTML format
            '<body>'
             +
            '<p><a href="' + DadosLista[i][3] + '"><img src="cid:imageKey" /width="300" height="300"></a></p>'
             +
            '<body>';

        MailApp.sendEmail({
            to : DadosLista[i][0],
            subject : DadosLista[i][0],
            htmlBody : body,
            inlineImages : {
                imageKey : blob
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you very much.